# Don't understand Review Ban

Tags: discussion, review-suspension

I was surprised when I found nothing in the review queues and discovered I have a review ban:

> Your reviews on
>   https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21401074,
>   https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21424554 wasn't
>   helpful. Please review the history of the posts and consider how
>   choosing a different action would help achieve that outcome more
>   quickly.

I looked at these two posts and discovered both had been converted to a comment by the same moderator. The first is debatable. The second, however, was a proposed tool to a question about tools.

In most discussions in Meta about what to do with answers to off-topic questions the consensus has been that the problem is the question, not the answer. If the question asks for tools, then an answer that suggests a tool is an answer. The question should be closed, not the answer penalized.

Further, most meta discussions (for example the [canonical](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)) about what is an answer and what not say that attempts to answer *are* answers, whether they're good answers or not. In both these cases it was an attempt to answer. The entries in "Similar questions" on this topic all got banned for proposing to delete not-so-great answers, not like in my case where I said these "Look OK".

So I am really feel confused, here.

Comment: The second one does not suggest any tool. It says "There are many plugins available [...]  if doesnt work try below". There is no additional info below? Which tools?

Comment: Is this type of ban temporal?

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij Yes; this is a temporary ban.

Answer (score 18):

I'm not the moderator who issued the review ban, but I agree with that decision. Neither of those answers was okay, and both should have been deleted. You marked both "Looks OK," thus the ban.

The first answer might as well have said, "I have no idea how to fix your Rails app; consider writing your app in a different language." That is not a meaningful answer. See [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

The second answer was somewhere between a non sequitur and a wild shot in the dark. The core of the question it was attempting to answer was:

> Is it possible to add a real time quick--inline (Ajax?)--editing customization to Blogger, like the one a Stack Exchange user gets at 2,000 reputation (See the attached picture)? This will help me in reducing lot of unwanted wastage of time.

But the answer was, essentially, "Go find a third-party plugin if that doesnt work clear your browser cache and reboot," complete with that quantity of spelling, grammatical, and sentence-structure errors. It was completely irrelevant to the problem.

You wrote,

> If the question asks for tools, then an answer that suggests a tool is an answer. The question should be closed, not the answer penalized.

Generally, this is correct. But the statement, "[T]here are many plugins available we can add and cutomize [sic]" (from the second answer you reviewed) is not "an answer that suggests a tool."

You also wrote,

> attempts to answer *are* answers, whether they're good answers or not

Again, this is true, but neither of these was a meaningful attempt to answer. "Rewrite your app in another language" and "reboot your computer to add a function to a web app" are not answers.

Comment: *"reboot your computer [...]" are not answers* apparently you haven't used Windows.

Comment: @Braiam The question was how to add new functionality (an Ajax-based quick edit function) to a website (Blogger, specifically). “Reboot your computer” is about as helpful an “answer” to that question as it would have been if the question was about how to do an oil change.

Comment: [Whoosh](https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/992/384/ded.gif)

Comment: @Braiam: under the new CoC you are obliged to suffix a joke with "note: this is a joke. Some people may not understand it and thus feel offended." (Note: this is a joke. Some people may not understand it and thus feel offended.)

Comment: @Braiam More like the joke [missed the target](https://goo.gl/images/HkGCaF).